# powershell function return bad result

Tags: windows, shell, powershell

I have this function that run a command as another user and return the result.

```
$OutputEncoding = [ System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8   
write-host (get-date -format s) " Beginning script..."
function getCreds()
{
    $Username = 'domain\user'
    $Password = 'test'
    $pass = ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText $Password -Force
    $Credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $UserName, $pass
    return $Credential;
}
function executeAsCryptUser($cmd){

write-host "cmd:"$cmd
$creds=getCreds
#Use System.Diagnostics to start the process as UserB
$ProcessInfo = New-Object System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo
#With FileName we're basically telling powershell to run another powershell process
$ProcessInfo.FileName = "powershell.exe"
#CreateNoWindow helps avoiding a second window to appear whilst the process runs
$ProcessInfo.CreateNoWindow = $true
#Note the line below contains the Working Directory where the script will start from
$ProcessInfo.WorkingDirectory = $env:windir
$ProcessInfo.RedirectStandardError = $true 
$ProcessInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = $true 
$ProcessInfo.UseShellExecute = $false
#The line below is basically the command you want to run and it's passed as text, as an argument
$ProcessInfo.Arguments = $cmd
#The next 3 lines are the credential for UserB, as you can see, we can't just pass $Credential
$ProcessInfo.Username = $creds.GetNetworkCredential().username
$ProcessInfo.Domain = $creds.GetNetworkCredential().Domain
$ProcessInfo.Password = $creds.Password
#Finally start the process and wait for it to finish
$Process = New-Object System.Diagnostics.Process 
$Process.StartInfo = $ProcessInfo 
$Process.Start() 
$Process.WaitForExit() 
#Grab the output
$GetProcessResult = $Process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd().ToString()
Write-host "Potential Error:"+ $Process.StandardError.ReadToEnd().ToString()
$result=$GetProcessResult.Trim()
write-Host "Debug output:"$result

return $result
}

$pop=executeAsCryptUser "whoami"
write-host "out:" $pop
```

When I run it it works, but I got a "True" injected in the return variable. I got the following output:

> out: True domain\test

If I debug the script and look at `$result` and find no trace of "True" in the variable.

What is the problem ?
Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem is that you're writing two values to the output-stream, which is used to transport values between functions (down the pipeline).

Where do the values come from:

```
  # Below return "True" to the output-stream
  $Process.Start()
  ...
  # Below appends the content of "result" and return from the function
  return $result
```

Read this [link](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2014/03/30/understanding-streams-redirection-and-write-host-in-powershell/) about streams. In short: Every return value of a command is written to the output stream, unless you're storing the result in a variable.

I think you need to change

`$Process.Start()`

to

`$Process.Start() | Out-Null`

Above line discards the `True` return value. As an alternative, you can store the result in a variable and keep it unused, like:

`$rv = $Process.Start()`

Also be aware that PowerShells `return` statement has different behavior, compared to e.g. the C# one.

Your line:

`return $result`

is equivalent to :

```
# Append content to output stream
$result
# return from the function
return
```

Read this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_return?view=powershell-6) for more info about return.

Hope that helps.